# If $K = \mathbb{C}(x)\left(\sqrt{-1 - x^{2}}\right)$, then $K = \mathbb{C}(t)$, where $t = (i - x)^{-1} \sqrt {- 1-x^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am working in the following problem:

Let $K = \mathbb{C}(x)\left(\sqrt{-1 - x^{2}}\right)$. I want to show that $[K:\mathbb{C}(x)] = 2$ and $K = \mathbb{C}(t)$ if $t = (i - x)^{-1} \sqrt {- 1-x^2}$.

For the first part, I used the polynomial $f(T) = T^{2} - (-1 - x^{2}) \in \mathbb{C}(x)[T]$. This polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{C}(x)$, because its roots are $\pm \sqrt{-1 - x^{2}} \notin \mathbb{C}(x)$. Since $f(T)$ has degree two and $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is a field, then $f(T)$ is irreducible in $C(x)[T]$. Therefore, $f(T)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{-1 - x^{2}}$. Then we have $[K:\mathbb{C}(x)] = \text{deg}(f) = 2$.

Now, for the second part, it is not difficult to show that $t \in \mathbb{C}(x)\left(\sqrt{-1 - x^{2}}\right) = K$, because $ (i - x )^{-1 }, \sqrt{-1 - x^{2}} \in \mathbb{C}(x)\left(\sqrt{-1 - x^{2}}\right)$. Then , we have $\mathbb{C}(t) \subseteq K$.

But I have a problem with the proof of $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}(t)$. How could I solve this?

Also, if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{R}$, that is, $K = \mathbb{R}(x)\left(\sqrt{-1 - x^{2}}\right)$, is there $t \in K$ such that $K = \mathbb{R}(t)$?

Comment: If I were the teacher giving this as an assignment, I would like you to justify the claim that $\sqrt{-1-x^2}\notin\Bbb{C}(x)$. After all, that claim plays a role similar to $\sqrt{5}\notin\Bbb{Q}$ elsewhere in the theory of extension fields.

Comment: For the second part... Have you tried using the fact $-1-x^2=(i-x)(i+x)$, allowing a rewrite $t=\sqrt{(i+x)/(i-x)}$? You have probably had an exercise saying that if $u=(ax+b)/(cx+d)$ with $ad-bc\neq0$, then $\Bbb{C}(u)=\Bbb{C}(x)$.

Comment: For the last part... Is $-1$ a sum of two squares in $\Bbb{R}(t)$?